# How to create a customToolbarOptions as "Search Google for ..."?

Tags: flutter

## Goal

Create a "Search Google for ..." context menu in Flutter app on selectable text.

### Expected Output

Similar to desktop Chrome context menu "Search Google for..."

## Trial

https://master-api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ToolbarOptions-class.html states "Create a custom ToolbarOptions if you want explicit control over the toolbar option." yet those are boolean values.